# How to Find Frequency while recording voice in iphone?

Tags: iphone, record, voice, frequency

In my application i have done to record the voice and playing in the device.
Now i want to find the audio frequency of that recorded voice(While recording). How can i find?.I dont have any idea. I have downloaded "aurio Touch" program.But its too difficult to understand me. So is there any tutorials are avilable(in iPhone)?. How can i achieve this?

Please guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involves math.  If that scares you, you should probably get/buy a library to do the analysis for you.  If not, [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) is a good place to start to see what's involved.  When I did this, I started by poking around [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)'s source code to get an idea of what's involved.

Comment: +1,@MarkPeters. Thanks for reply.I dont use any software depends on my requirement. so i can use only FFT and is there any sample code availble for that?. Thanks.

Comment: @Pugal Devan: As I said, Audacity has code for a FFT that you can tinker with.  There's a function of Audacity called a "Power Spectrum" which takes a sample and plots the power of the component frequencies.  It's not made for an iPhone but the code itself is pretty easy to understand if you have a basic understanding of C.